# Switching between img using jquery and attr()

Tags: javascript, jquery, attr

I honestly don't understand what's going on that the first image that it renders and does the fadeIn and fadeOut it's being the wrong one.

If someone could explain to me what I am doing wrong I would appreciate.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var $text01 = $("#text1");
  var $text02 = $("#text2");
  var $text03 = $("#text3");
  var $text04 = $("#text4");

  var $imgController = $("#img-controller");

  var images = ['https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/927x637q90/913/D4xyiG.jpg', 'https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/333x250q90/673/qVKDU3.jpg']

  for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    if (i + 1 == images.length) {
      $imgController.attr('src', images[i]).fadeOut(4000);
      i = 0;
      $imgController.atrr('src', images[i]).fadeIn(4000);
    } else {
      $imgController.attr('src', images[i]).fadeOut(4000);
      $imgController.attr('src', images[i + 1]).fadeIn(4000);
      i++
    }
  }

})
```

```css
body {
  color: white;
}
.bg {
  position: fixed !important;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  #text1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 35%;
    left: 25%;
    font-size: 10em;
    color: $inizio-green;
    p {
      text-shadow: 2px 0px 4px rgba(150, 150, 150, 1);
      -webkit-text-stroke: 1px $primary-color;
    }
  }
  #text2 {
    @extend #text1;
  }
  #text3 {
    @extend #text1;
  }
  #text4 {
    @extend #text1;
  }
}
.container-fluido {
  position: absolute;
  width: 60%;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20%;
  padding: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 10px;
  background-color: $secondary-color;
  @include opacity(0.7);
}
.img-logo {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.img-background {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.menu {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 30px;
  li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 40px;
    a {
      text-decoration: none;
      transition: border-bottom linear 0.5s;
      color: $primary-color;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    a:hover {
      border-bottom: 1px solid $inizio-green;
    }
  }
  li:first-child {
    padding-left: 20%;
  }
}
$primary-color:white;
 $secondary-color:#2A2A2A;
 $inizio-green:#B7C630;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="bg">
  <img id="img-controller" src="https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/927x637q90/913/D4xyiG.jpg" />

  <div id="text1">
    <p>ANTONELLO</p>
  </div>
  <div id="text2">
    <p>DONATELLO</p>
  </div>
  <div id="text3">
    <p>BOTTICELLI</p>
  </div>
  <div id="text4">
    <p>GALILEO</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluido">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="navbar">
      <img class="img-logo" src="http://i58.tinypic.com/15mhjq1.png" />
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">EMPRESA</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">EMPREENDIMENTOS</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">PORTFÓLIO</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTATO</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
  </div>
</div>
<div>
</div>
```

The code is also on [CodePen Playground](http://codepen.io/rcidaleassumpo/pen/WbymZy/)

Thank you

Comment: you need to use the callback for `fadeOut`.

Comment: You want explanation or the code which is already working well??

Comment: Use .prop() instead of .attr() to stay current and later avoid migration problems.

Answer (score 1):

May be this will help.

```
images.forEach(function(el, index, arr) {
 $imgController.attr('src', images[i]).fadeOut(4000, function(){
    $imgController.attr('src', images[i+1]).fadeIn(4000)
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be an assumption, but are you looking for a loop? The reason your image stays the same is due the the foreach running before the first fadeOut even happens, actively changing instantly to the latest image in the array. You could use a setInterval to make it loop infinitely:

```
var i = 1;
setInterval(function(){
    $imgController.fadeOut(2000, function(){
        $imgController.attr('src', images[i]).fadeIn(2000, function(){
            i++;
            if(i > (images.length - 1)){
                i = 0;
            }
        });
    });
}, 6000);
```

Here is an example: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/96mv5qwo/)

Let me know if I am way off base with you wanting this looped. Hope this helps!